# Make a request in the prestashop BO reference column list of product

Tags: sql, prestashop

For the "Reference" column in the list of PrestaShop products in the BO.
Do you have any idea how to do a search that will point to a join?
In AdminProductController

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In PrestaShop 1.7.8.10, I believe it's not possible without overriding the code. When examining the function ```getCatalogProductList()``` in ```src/Adapter/Product/AdminProductDataProvider.php```, the search value is used in the MySQL WHERE condition as ```pl.[column] LIKE %[value]%```.